# UIImage > NSData > NSString fail

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uiimage, nsdata

I know this question has been questioned many times, but my problem is a little different. I have an image (shared.image) and I want to upload the data to a server. This is the code (the img: bit is just a way to let the server know that is an image, not a string):

```
NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img:%@", UIImagePNGRepresentation(shared.image)];
NSData *imageData = [imageString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[shared.outputStream write:[imageData bytes] maxLength:[imageData length]];
```

When the server responds back (as a string), this is the other code (shared.array is an array which groups all of the strings in case of packet fragmentation. The img: bit is deleted):

```
string = [shared.imageArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

I nslogged [UIImage imageWithData:data] and it returns nil.
What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you read the server response as NSData and convert it from NSData to UIImage? Are you sure the server responds back with an image?

Comment: Unfortunately no because I have no idea if there is an NSData equivalent in Python (the server is written in Python)

Comment: No. That is not what I was asking. Why are you storing the response from server as string - that is what I am asking.

Comment: the code is from the raywenderlich tutorial, which handles text responses as a string

Answer (score 4):

Why are you round-tripping to a `NSString` when you have binary data? If you want to load `imageData` with the contents of your image, you would bypass the `NSString` altogether:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(shared.image);
```

If your server accepts binary data, that's all you need.

If it needs text string, then your proposed code will not accomplish the job, but rather you should use something like Base64 to encode it (e.g. using [Matt Gallager's NSData+Base64 category](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html)). For example:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(shared.image);
NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img:\"%@\"", [imageData base64EncodedString]];
```

Please note that in the response, I'd suggest enclosing the Base64 encoded string in quotes. That way, the recipient can detect the end of the Base64-encoded string. FYI, I've tried to respect your interface of `img:`, but you could also contemplate using the standard [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), perhaps something like:

```
NSString *imageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img:\"data:image/png;base64,%@\"", [imageData base64EncodedString]];
```

It's up to you.

In terms of parsing the server response, again, it's a question of whether it is a string (in which case it should be a Base64 representation of the data), or whether it's binary data (in which case, you should just be appending the data to your `NSMutableData` and then just using `imageWithData`).

Comment: I wanted to do that, but I need to put the data in a string because of the img: prefix (it is used by the server to know what data it received). But I will try the base64 library

Comment: @GreatGoldApps This is a curious interface, where you have a text prefix to a binary data stream. Or if the server expected Base64, I would have thought that this would have been an explicit part of the interface. You shouldn't just "try" Base64, but you should really nail down what the web service is expecting, and code for that. Are you uploading and downloading from your own web service? Or are you interfacing with some established web service? Can you share the particulars with us?

Comment: The server is mine. The code is from this raywenderlich tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Comment: @GreatGoldApps Then it's all a question of how you write the server side of the interface. With a low-level sockets interface, you certainly could use binary, but if so, you'd probably have to communicate how many bytes of image data are forthcoming (because if you keep the socket connection open, there's otherwise no easy way to know when the image is complete). Base64 encoding is almost certainly easier, though less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have never programmed in Python, so I really have no idea on how to communicate bytes in Python, but if Base64 will make my life easier, I will definitely use it.

Comment: @GreatGoldApps I've updated my answer with Base64 example. Note the use of quotes.

Comment: Got it, I will try it out this evening

Comment: The conversion does work, but do I need to set something on the server as well, because the data I receive from the server is NULL?

Answer (score 4):

for IOS >= 7

```
- (NSString *)imageToNSString:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    return [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}

- (UIImage *)stringToUIImage:(NSString *)string
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:string
                                                      options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```